# Running a Python Script Inside Another Directory

Tags: python

I have the following Python script inside a directory called 'test' on my Linux desktop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('test.txt','w')
f.write('testing the script')
```

So it's `/Home/Desktop/test/script.py`

If I go inside the directory and type `./script.py` it works fine and creates the test.txt file.

However for some reason I am not able to run the script from the Desktop (`/Home/Desktop`). I tried `./test/script.py`, for instance, but didn't work.

The file permissions on the script are `755`, and on the directory `777`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the error message you're seeing on the console?

Comment: No error message, so I guess the script is executing but not being able to create the file.

Comment: If it weren't able to create the file, it should throw an I/O error.  I'm guessing it is creating the file, just not where you expect it.  Also, as mentioned in my answer, 'w' mode truncates the file, so you won't see any changes if the file exists (except modified time).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `os.path.dirname()` and `__file__` to get absolute paths like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os  # We need this module

# Get path of the current dir, then use it to create paths:
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'test.txt')

# Then work using the absolute paths:
f = open(file_path,'w')
f.write('testing the script')
```

This way the script **will work on files placed only in the same directory** as the script, regardless of the place from which you execute it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot man. I am guessing without that change the script was being executed, but it was not being able to create the file cause it was trying to place it at /Desktop instead of /Desktop/test, correct?

Comment: @DanielS: Exactly! :) I am happy I helped.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If your cwd is `/Desktop/test`, and then you try to execute `./test/script.py`, you're trying to run a script at `/Desktop/test/test/script.py`.  More likely, you just wanted to do `./script.py`.

As an aside, your question would have been more useful if you had provided the error message you got from the command line, rather than just saying "didn't work"

If the script is running and nothing is echoed to the console, most likely it's working.  Note that [opening a file in 'w' mode truncates the file](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open).  Maybe you want to use a+?

Comment: No error message, which I now realize must mean the script is executing, but the file is not being opened/created, right?

Comment: @DanielS sounds like it - might be worth putting in a print statement just for a sanity check . . .does test.txt exist and what are it's permissions?

Comment: I'll explore more to see if I discover what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

In your `open('test.txt', 'w')` put `open(r'./test.txt', 'w')`. When you run it, use "python `script.py`. See if that works.

Comment: You mean use python ./test/script.py? Cause as I said I am trying to run the script from outside its directory.

Comment: Yes. I figured that you could generalize the parameters to the `python` executable.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you also mean open(r'./test.txt','w') or open('./test.txt','w'), without the 'r').

Comment: No, I meant the `r`, it's useful for not having to explicitly delimit strings (especially those containing paths). See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm

Answer (score 0):

"And so on" doesn't meant much.

Where in the file-system are you?  What is the test
directories relative position to your location?

Have you tried a fully qualified path?
E.g.,

```
/home/daniel/test/script.py
```

Comment: I am on the Desktop, and 'test' directory is inside it. I edited the question to contain this info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What directory are you executing in?
You might try using:

```
import os

print os.getcwd()
```

to verify that the working directory is what you think it is.