# Python - Resolve to an absolute path relative to a script file

Tags: bash

I am using a find statement to execute python scripts which are in sub folders of all sub folders of the current directory

The find statement is `find . -name \process.py -type f -exec python3 {} \;`

The problem I am encountering is that the script is using relative paths e.g `..\data` for retrieving other resources. These relative paths are resolved as required when the script is executed individually by running it from its directory but when running the script from a parent directory two levels up using the `find` command the path resolves relative to that parent directory causing errors

Comment: The answer was found here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790986/running-a-python-script-inside-another-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-execdir` option of the [find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command:

Having the following folder structure in `/tmp`:

```
/test
/test/subdir1
/test/subdir1/subdir2
/test/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3
```

and a `r.py` file in each folder:

```
# r.py
import os
dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dirpath)
```

You have the output:

```
/tmp/test
/tmp/test/subdir1
/tmp/test/subdir1/subdir2
/tmp/test/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in python I suggest looking at this answer:
[How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

It is always better to find an absolute path, If using bash:

```
readlink -f filename
```